# Get element value from react ui material elements (ex: listitemtext)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have put an `onClick()` event in which I call a function to get the value of any element clicked inside the HTML body and display it inside a web component.

```
<div id="root" onclick="traiteClick(event)"></div>
```

This is how I get the clicked object inside the `traiteClick()` function.

```
let object = document.getElementById(evt.target.id).innerHTML;
```

This works with HTML elements since I can give them ids but not with my ui material elements.

```
<ListItemText className='test' primary="Date de naissance" secondary={artist?.lifeSpan?.begin} />
```

I tied using `getElementsByClassName` but it didn't work.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The read-only target property of the Event interface is a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched.

You don't need to get an id and use it to find an object. Just use `event.target` or `event.currentTarget`.

Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)